# Overriding Standard NEW Button with LC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

Trying to override the NEW button 'Standart button' to Lightning component.

In My Lightning component i am calling LWC.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,lightning:actionOverride,flexipage:availableForRecordHome, force:lightningQuickAction"
                access="global">
    <c:createBillingProcess />
</aura:component>
```

**HTML:**

```
<template  >
        <div class="demo-only">
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large"
                aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1">
                <div class="slds-modal__container" style="width: 50%;">
                    <header class="slds-modal__header">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse"
                            title="Close">
                            <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" size="medium" onclick={navigateToObjectHome}>
                            </lightning-icon>
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                        </button>
                        <h2 id="modal-heading-01-addemercont" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">
                            Create New Billing Process
                        </h2>
                    </header>
                    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1-addemercont">

                        

                    </div>
                    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <lightning-button label="Cancel" variant="neutral" onclick={navigateToObjectHome}>
                        </lightning-button>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <lightning-button type="submit" variant="brand" value="AddEContact" name="AddEContact"
                            label="Save" onclick={navigateToObjectHome}>
                        </lightning-button>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from "lwc";
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";

export default class CreateBillingProcess extends NavigationMixin(
  LightningElement
) {
   

  navigateToObjectHome() {
    // alert("in");
    this.closeBillingprocessModal = false;
    // Navigate to the Account home page
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: "standard__objectPage",
      attributes: {
        objectApiName: "Billing__c",
        actionName: "list"
      }
    });
  }
 
  
}
```

On very Fist, When i click on New button Modal popup Open, and Click of `close/ cancel` button it back to list view `NavigationMixin.Navigate` -- this work perfect.

Without Refreshing the Page when i again click on NEW button, It's shows blank blue screen.
When i Refresh the whole page and try It's working.

At very First after refreshing the page I's working, If i do the same without refreshing the page It's not working.Can any one help me out on this.

Comment: Where's this "new" button that you are mentioning? I only see a "Save" and "Cancel" buttons in your code.

Comment: New Button is the Standard Button, Override  the Standard button, (in List view page of the custom object)